# How to compare a List and string and find the matching words in the string using c#?

Tags: c#, string, list

The list and string are:

```
string Text;
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
```

Now loading data to the list from database:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=SANGEEN-PC;Initial Catalog=IS_Project;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=0";

using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     try
     {
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select NamesValues from Names", cnn);
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         da.Fill(ds, "Names");

         foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["Names"].Rows)
         {
             Names.Add(row["NamesValues"].ToString());
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
     }
 }
```

Now loading data to string:

```
Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Data-Sanitization-Project\Files\Test.txt");
```

Now I want to compare the Names and Text such that:

1. Find all List items that are also in string (matched Words) and store it in list or array.
2. Replace all the found matched Words with "Names".
3. Count the the Matched words.

Example:

```
Names:                  Text:                                

Sangeen Khan           I am Sangeen Khan and i am friend    
Jhon                   Jhon. Jhon is friend of Wasim.                               
Wasim
Alexander
Afridi
```

Desired operation:

```
Matched List/Array:    Matches:         Updated Text:         

 Sangeen Khan            4            I am "Name" and i am friend                 
 Jhon                                "Name". "Name" is friend of "Names".
 Wasim
```

For the above three points, I have written the following code, but it's not working:

```
var TextRead = File.ReadAllLines(text);
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>(TextRead);

foreach (string i in Names)
{
   if (hashSet.Contains(i))
   {
       MessageBox.Show("found");
   }
}
```

I have try my best to explain my problem, however, feel free to edit my question if you understand that i need to be edit. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using hashset when earlier you have List<string>? Have you tried Names.Contains()?

Comment: @David Lindon the Text is string and i ma trying to find words in that string Text. i don't think .Contains() could be using with string

Comment: For the count, you want to count all substrings or only matching words? What is a word in your definition? Is it separated by space or also punctuation chars, which chars?

Comment: You noticed that your text only contains `Jhon` once because the other one is `Jhnon`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Find all List items that are also in string (matched Words) and store it in list or array.
2. Replace all the found matched Words with "Names".
3. Count the the Matched words.

---

1. `List<string> matchedWords = Names.Where(Text.Contains).ToList();`
2. `matchedWords.ForEach(w => Text = Text.Replace(w, "Names"));`
3. `int numMatchedWords = matchedWords.Count;`

It seems `numMatchedWords` should count all matches in the text, so even repeating. Then you can use following approach (before the `Replace`):

This extension finds the number of occurrences of all words in a text:

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> OccurencesInText(this IEnumerable<string> words, string text, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(text));

    Dictionary<string, int> resultDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (string word in words.Distinct())
    {
        int wordOccurrences = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < text.Length - word.Length; i++)
        {
            string substring = text.Substring(i, word.Length);
            if (substring.Equals(word, comparison)) wordOccurrences++;
        }
        resultDict.Add(word, wordOccurrences);
    }
    return resultDict;
}
```

Usage:

```
int numMatchedWords = matchedWords.OccurencesInText(Text).Sum(kv => kv.Value);
```

Comment: I don't think this is exactly what OP wants. Looking at his example, the number of matches should be 4 ("Jhon" is repeated) With your code, the matches would be 3...

Comment: Hmm..was just checking. I think you've got another problem, as to count the matches you split the text into words, but some names (Sangeen Khan) are two words in fact. That's why in my answer i first replace the names and then count :)

Comment: Oh yes, but OP says in the example he expects 4 matches,so i assumed it was a typo (i guess also instead of Jhon OP meant John ;)

Comment: It give me the error:
Error CS1061 'List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'OccurencesInText' and no extension method 'OccurencesInText' accepting a first argument of type 'List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Comparing terms C:\Users\sange\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Comparing terms\Comparing terms\Form1.cs 103 Active

Comment: @Tim Schmelter , it is  not working if i load list from the database

Comment: I don't know why but it give me error that:  String cannot be of zero length.
on this line:matchedWords.ForEach(w => Text = Text.Replace(w, "Names"));

Comment: @SangeenKhan: then the list `Names` from database contained an empty string `""`. Of course you have to skip those. Either with SQL or where you fill the list or at the LINQ query which uses the `Where`. [`String.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) throws this exception(as you can see in the documentation) if the oldvalue was an empty string.

Comment: @SangeenKhan: _What_ problem? Ask another question with missing informations or edit your question to include the problem that you had

Answer (score 0):

You can run your Names in a Loop and search the Name with Regex,
Ist the Match.Count > 0 then you can replace the the text and count up your 
global MatchCount.

Is the Match.Count == 0.
Then you can add this name in second List...then you can remove the names from the list after a for Each Loop.

```
        public static List<string> Names = new List<string>();
    public static string Text = "I am Sangeen Khan and i am friend Jhon. Jhon is friend of Wasim.";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Names.Add("Sangeen Khan");
        Names.Add("Jhon");
        Names.Add("Wasim");
        Names.Add("Alexander");
        Names.Add("Afridi");

        var matchCount = 0;
        var nameToRemove = new List<string>();
        foreach (var name in Names)
        {
            var regex = new Regex(name);
            var match = regex.Matches(Text);

            //Count of matches
            matchCount += match.Count;

            if (match.Count > 0)
            {
                Text = regex.Replace(Text, "\"Name\"");
            }
            else
            {
                nameToRemove.Add(name);
            }
        }
        nameToRemove.ForEach(name=> Names.Remove(name));
        Console.WriteLine($"Names: {string.Join(" ", Names)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Count: {matchCount}");
        Console.WriteLine($"ReplaceText: {Text}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Output

Names: Sangeen Khan Jhon Wasim

Count: 4

ReplaceText: I am "Name" and i am friend "Name". "Name" is friend of "Name".

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main()
    {
        var count = 0;

        string text = "I am Sangeen Khan and i am friend Jhon. Jhnon is friend of Wasim.     ";
        List<string> Names = new List<string>() {"Sangeen Khan ", "Jhon","Wasim","Alexander","Afridi" };
        List<string> matchedList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var name in Names)
        {
            if(text.Contains(name))
            {
                text = text.Replace(name, "\"Name\" ");
                matchedList.Add(name);
                count++;
            }
        }

        foreach (var name in matchedList)
        {                
             Console.WriteLine(name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.WriteLine(text);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to replace the names in your list with 'Name', i would do that first and the count the occurences 'Name' in your text. Something like:

```
string[] names = new string[] { "Sangeen Khan", "Jhon", "Wasim", "Alexander", "Afridi" };
string text = "I am Sangeen Khan and i am friend Jhon. Jhon is friend of Wasim.";

foreach(string name in names)
{
    text = text.Replace(name, "'Name'");
}

int matches = Regex.Matches(Regex.Escape(text), "'Name'").Count;
```

Comment: My dear friend the list is loading from the database , when i load list from the database ur code dose not work

Comment: @SangeenKhan Then you should debug your code to see what's in the list when you load it from the DB...